# How to prevent from page refresh on submit button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have form with one input and one submit button.

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' id="form_search">
<input type='hidden' name="action" id="form_1" value='1' />
</span><input id="query" type="text" name="mol" value="">
<input type='submit' value='Search' name="Search" id="Search" />
```

on form submission form input data goes to php below code

```
if (isset($_POST['Search'])) {
$_SESSION["query"] = $_POST["mol"];
$_SESSION["action"] = $_POST["action"];
}
```

i want to avoid page refresh on form submission. i tried e.preventDefault() and return false; 
methods in my java script but not working(this methods helping me from page refresh but does not allowing me to send data to php code)

please help me out of this problem, please suggest working ajax code for this problem.

Comment: You just have to prevent default form submiting by using return false or e.preventDefault(). And send your form info to PHP side through AJAX

Comment: Hi, @Hossein Sh could you please provide me ajax code to send form info to PHP side (as you mentioned). Please provide me working code.

Comment: Hi @sugit, Exactly I don't know what you mean. But as I understand you can gathers inputs and send them as JSON data, or serialize your form data and send them again as a JSON to your PHP file and access it with `$_POST` or `$_GET`

Answer (score 5):

Page refresh will delete you previous data so to reserve it you can use $.post() or $.ajax()

You can prevent page refreshing by adding one of these two things in event handler function

for pure js

```
 return false;
```

for jquery you can use

```
e.preventDefault(); // e is passed to handler
```

Your complete code will be something like

using **$.post()** in js

```
function checkfunction(obj){
$.post("your_url.php",$(obj).serialize(),function(data){
 alert("success");
 });
 return false;
 }
```

html

```
<input type='submit' onclick="return checkfunction(this)" />
```

or same effect with onsubmit

```
<form  onsubmit="return checkfunction(this)" method="post">
```

Comment: i have "post" method in form. return false; and e.preventDefault();  functions not allowing me to send values to php code.

Comment: on form submit button click, i dont want to execute any code rather only form values should get passed to php.

Comment: @sujit edited. see you have to use ajax($.post in example) to send data in order to prevent this problem

Comment: @sujit are u sure you want to use AJAX? You have to send form data through AJAX as A.B said

Answer (score 0):

Without ajax you can simply add the checked attribute in PHP. So for example if your radio group has the name `radio` and one has value `a`, the other `b`:

```
<?php
$a_checked = $_POST['radio'] === 'a';
$b_checked = $_POST['radio'] === 'b';
?>

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="a"<?=($a_checked ? ' checked' : '')?>></input>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="b"<?=($b_checked ? ' checked' : '')?>></input>
```

So when a user submits the form and you display it again, it will be like the user submitted it even the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="rbutton" id="r1">R1
<input type="radio" name="rbutton" id="r2">R2
<input type="button" id="go" value="SUBMIT" />
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#go').click(function(){
        var val1 = $('input:radio[name=rbutton]:checked').val();
        var datastring = "partialName="+val1;
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```